# How to find path between two nodes on a minimum spanning tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search, path-finding

I have minimum spanning tree and I have created list of adjacency. With help of this list of adjacency I run DFS algorithm and it works correctly.
Problem is that I want to get path between two nodes.
Example Tree:
[image]

For example I want to get path from 4 to 6
**Current output**: 4-3-1-7-2-5-6
**Wanted output**: 4-3-5-6

Code:

```
void Graph::DFS(int source, int destination)
{
    Visited[source - 1] = true;

    vector<pair<int,int>> adjList = MSTAdjacencyLists[source - 1]; //first is vertice, second is weight

    cout << source << "-";
   
    for (int i = 0; i < adjList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (adjList[i].first == destination)
        {
            cout << adjList[i].first <<"\nFound!!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (Visited[adjList[i].first-1] == false)
        {
            DFS(adjList[i].first, destination);
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that DFS can be helpful but maybe there are better methods?

Comment: Where do you putput the found path? At the moment you output every node you visit regardless of whether its useful or not

Comment: Yeah, you are printing inappropriately soon.  Only print nodes after you find the destination.

Comment: Ok, maybe I asked it wrong. I want to refactor code to print only useful nodes

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as a step-by-step logical process using short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested cos no small test availble

```
bool Graph::DFS(int source, int destination) <<<<====== bool return
{
    Visited[source - 1] = true;

    vector<pair<int,int>> adjList = MSTAdjacencyLists[source - 1]; //first is vertice, second is weight

    
   
    for (int i = 0; i < adjList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (adjList[i].first == destination)
        {
            cout << adjList[i].first <<"\nFound!!" << endl;
            return true;
        }

        if (Visited[adjList[i].first-1] == false)
        {
            if(DFS(adjList[i].first, destination))
            {
                cout << source << "-";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

ie DFS indicates whether it found the destination or not, when unwinding the recursion print the path that returned true

Not sure if we need the first 'cout << source' that I moved.

Comment: Unfortunely does not work. Printing only "3-"

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I managed to find solution. This article was very helpful for me. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-the-path-between-any-two-nodes-of-a-tree-dfs/
Idea of using stack and backtracking is really smart.
Code after solution:

```
void Graph::DFS(int source, int destination, vector<int> stack)
{
    Visited[source - 1] = true;
    stack.push_back(source);
    vector<pair<int,int>> adjList = MSTAdjacencyLists[source - 1];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < adjList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (adjList[i].first == destination)
        {
            stack.push_back(adjList[i].first);
            printPath(stack);
            return;
        }

        if (Visited[adjList[i].first-1] == false)
        {
            DFS(adjList[i].first, destination,stack);
        }
    }

    stack.pop_back();
}
```